# How switch localization for all Content Items and localizable strings in Orchard Cms

Tags: localization, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I want create [switching links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdQa0.png) between cultures for changing culture of all content items and all localizable strings. How I can implement this for Orchard 1.10?

Comment: I would try to implement my own `Orchard.Localization.IText`. If you dig into the default implementation there is a line `_localizedStringManager.GetLocalizedString(_scope, textHint, currentCulture)` and here you can pass the culture as third parameter. Or maybe customize the `WorkContext`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial video on youtube, have a look:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6Tt8vjlOVw

Basically you need the following modules

1. culture picker (to provide a culture picker)
2. localization (to localize content items)

There is also a module called OrchardCMS.Localization-Extensions on GitHub

https://github.com/urbanit/OrchardCMS.Localization-Extensions

Comment: Thanks! I add localization part to my contetnt types and to layout. But I could not enable front-end culture picker for front-end. I had to create it yourself